# Can someone explain radiosity lighting to me?

Tags: lighting, minecraft

I already have the basics of ambient occlusion down. I have a raycaster and am capable of shooting rays about a hemisphere uniformly. It seems like those are the basics of what are needed for radiosity but I don't know where to go from there. Do I find how much light comes from each face? (I'm making my game out of cubes like minecraft) After that what do I do?

Comment: As a note, radiosity tends to be much harder to implement than ray tracing, and is also usually slower. If you already have the ray-cast code, maybe it would be worth exploring a ray traced rendering engine? To the best of my knowledge, there is more information and public papers on raytracing. If you do choose to go that route, check out ompf.org, it is a forum for rt devs everywhere from photorealistic to real-time (what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in computer graphics "theory", I'd highly recommend Foley/van Dam:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Principles-Practice-2nd/dp/0201848406](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406)

If you're just interested in what it is, and how it works, Wikipedia has a great article (with visual examples and math equations):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosity_%283D_computer_graphics%29

And for an over-simplified one-liner, I guess you could say "radiosity is a more sophisticated technique for rending ambient lighting in a ray traced image".

IMHO ...

Answer (score 3):

Radiosity, in simple terms, is a two stage algorithm to compute illumination.
It works as follows:

first stage: For every pair of polygons in the scene, you compute "how much they can see of each other". E.g. take a cube: none of the faces see another face of the cube. If you invert the cube to a room: opposite inner walls see each other completely.

second stage: With this 'visibility information', called 'form factors', you can now distribute the light energy progressively through out the scene. At iteration 0, all the energy is in the light-source faces, and this is then transferred onto other faces. At subsequent iterations, more faces are transmitting energy into the scene (indirect illumination).

Drawback: does diffuse illumination only
Strength: once computed, the lighting is viewpoint independent so that static scenes can be "walked through" without recomputing lighting.